# web scraping - program doesn't read a tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape this website:

```
http://acfarma.com.br/encontre-uma-farmacia/?cidade=Nova%20Veneza&bairro=CENTRO
```

My expected result is to print the text.
And I did this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

request = requests.get("http://acfarma.com.br/encontre-uma-farmacia/?cidade=Mafra&bairro=CENTRO")  #abaeté - centro
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')

for ultag in soup.find_all('li'):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('div'):
        print(litag.text)
```

But is doesn't return anything. It says it's empty. I've tried using all the possible tags ('ul', 'li', 'div') and combine them, but I failed to get my results.

Expected output:

```
FARMACIA DUMINELLI E GORINI LTDA ME
Rua Conego Miguel Giaca, 14
Cidade: Nova Veneza
Bairro: Centro
Estado: SC
CEP: 88865-000
Telefone: 3436-2045
Email: veneza@acfarma.com.br

FARMACIA GORINI LTDA ME
Rua Dos Imigrantes, 357
Cidade: Nova Veneza
Bairro: Centro
Estado: SC
CEP: 88865-000
Telefone: 3436-1347
Email: gorini@acfarma.com.br
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried searching by xpath or class name or ID?

Comment: The data you are looking for are postloaded after the webpage. You should consider to use Selenium to get your data

Comment: You can hit this url to get some well formatted data I think.
http://acfarma.com.br/wp-content/plugins/entrefarma-map/json_formatter.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Md Mahfuzur Rahman's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907649/web-scraping-program-doesnt-read-a-tag#comment96583013_54907649) you can get all data without using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://acfarma.com.br/wp-content/plugins/entrefarma-map/json_formatter.json').json()
for r in response:
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'id': '159', 'endereco': 'AVENIDA PRESIDENTE DUTRA', 'numero': '18', 'complemento': '', 'bairro': 'CENTRO', 'cep': '88860-000', 'cidade': 'Siderópolis', 'estado': 'SC', 'ddd': '48', 'telefone': '3435-3692', 'email': 'drogasider@acfarma.com.br', 'latitude': '-28.5994988', 'longitude': '-49.42558963', 'nome': 'DROGASIDER COMERCIO DE MEDICAMENTOS E MANIPULACAO LTDA - ME - MATRIZ', 'descricao': '', 'tags': '', 'autor': ''}
```

etc.

Or if you're looking for filtered data, e.g. `cidade=Nova Veneza` and `bairro=CENTRO` then:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://acfarma.com.br/wp-content/plugins/entrefarma-map/json_formatter.json').json()
for r in response:
    if r['cidade'] == 'Nova Veneza' and r['bairro'] == 'CENTRO':
        print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'id': '167', 'endereco': 'RUA CONEGO MIGUEL GIACA', 'numero': '14', 'complemento': '', 'bairro': 'CENTRO', 'cep': '88865-000', 'cidade': 'Nova Veneza', 'estado': 'SC', 'ddd': '48', 'telefone': '3436-2045', 'email': 'veneza@acfarma.com.br', 'latitude': '-28.6647154', 'longitude': '-49.4729414', 'nome': 'FARMACIA DUMINELLI E GORINI LTDA ME', 'descricao': '', 'tags': '', 'autor': ''}
{'id': '168', 'endereco': 'RUA DOS IMIGRANTES', 'numero': '357', 'complemento': 'EDIFICIO BISTEK', 'bairro': 'CENTRO', 'cep': '88865-000', 'cidade': 'Nova Veneza', 'estado': 'SC', 'ddd': '48', 'telefone': '3436-1347', 'email': 'gorini@acfarma.com.br', 'latitude': '-28.6370762', 'longitude': '-49.5055401', 'nome': 'FARMACIA GORINI LTDA ME', 'descricao': '', 'tags': '', 'autor': ''}
```

Comment: thanks! the output its not exacly what I wanted because it's not pretty, but it works perfeclty and does the job. I will use it. Thanks for the help